# Roc curve python

Tags: python, roc

I need to plot a Roc Curve such as :
[roc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Na4yA.png), because I have to test an algorithm for outlier detection

How can I to plot this in python? In particular how can I calculate Detection Rate ?

Comment: Visit sklearn page at: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-roc-py

Comment: What do you mean by Detection Rate? Detection of what ?

Comment: I also recommend reading [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S016786550500303X) paper (the sklearn notes reference it) for understanding the ROC metric.

Comment: I mean outlier detection, so detection rate is the number of outliers found on the totals

Answer (score 1):

One of the best way I've found to deal with ROC curve is to utilize [scikit-plot](https://github.com/reiinakano/scikit-plot) library. Just one line is enough. Here's an example -

```
import scikitplot
scikitplot.metrics.plot_roc_curve(y_true, y_probas)
plt.show()
```

Giving even multi-class outputs (image taken from its GitHub webpage)
[image: plt]

Comment: Thanks for bringing this library to my attention!

Comment: My problem is different, I don't have true postive rate but i have detection rate